# Convert to utf8 two byte encoded data PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have some data in a database, showing as the below:

#### **Ã¸Ã¥Ã±Ã‰Ã©**

Judging from [this](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) `Ã¸` should be a `Ÿ`. I'm not sure of a few things, but so far my research seems to be pointing toward the fact that these are encoded using two byte UTF8, but are showing as single bytes, hence one character (Ÿ) shows as two (Ã and ¸).

So how do I convert it? At the moment I have tried the following:

```
$text = "Ã¸Ã¥Ã±Ã‰Ã©"; 
echo "Original: " . $text . "<br/>";
echo "iconv detect: " . iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text) . "<br/>";
echo "ASCII convert: " . iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text) . "<br/>";  
echo "MB Convert: " . mb_convert_encoding($text, "UTF-8", "iso-8859-1") . "<br/>";  

// Wrong way around?

echo "ASCII convert: " . iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $text) . "<br/>";  
echo "MB Convert: " . mb_convert_encoding($text, "iso-8859-1", "UTF-8") . "<br/>";
```

> Original: Ã¸Ã¥Ã±Ã‰Ã©
>
> iconv detect: Ã¸Ã¥Ã±Ã‰Ã©
>
> ASCII convert:
>
> MB Convert: ÃÂ¸ÃÂ¥ÃÂ±Ãâ°ÃÂ©
>
> ASCII convert:
>
> MB Convert: øåñ�?é

Its worth noting that this is just for the special characters, all of abcdefghijkl.... are all fine, its just accented and special characters that are going insane.

Comment: Which encoding was used to save the file? It's relevant since you are not fetching the "Ã¸Ã¥Ã±Ã‰Ã©" from the database in your example

Comment: Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) / Connection Collation: utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I have it – but in case any one in future needs it:

```
$text = "JÃ¸rgen FurÃ¸y HÃ¥kansson SahlÃ©n";

echo "Original: ". $text . "<br/>";
echo "Windows iconv: " . iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$text) . "<br/>";
```

Gives:

```
Original: JÃ¸rgen FurÃ¸y HÃ¥kansson SahlÃ©n
Windows iconv: JørgenFurøy Håkansson Sahlén
```

So its the all important `Windows-1252`:

```
iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252",$text)
```

Comment: Oh just when I answered haha, typical!

Comment: Wow, this is a really old post. But this might have just saved me from the biggest headache of my life!